# Autoresizing does not work with Xib in xcode 7.2

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I've never used a Xib before and it's giving me a lot of problems right now. The autoresizing option in the Size Inspector tab is not working. The view does not change from device to device, it just stays the same and either cuts off part of the screen or adds blank white space. How do I make my layout fit the screen no matter what device is being used?

How about instead of editing my posts, you give me an answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

Try using size classes. That way you can adjust elements for each type.

[image]

Comment: How do I edit elements for each type so they fit on all screens the same? Idk how to use size classes

Comment: What should I do to make it fit the screen like the rest of my views do

Comment: Take 10 minutes and go through some size classes tutorials. Then you will see how you can make adjust each object differently on each page.